# Commit to develop branch directly in Git Flow?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-flow

I'm currently migrating a project to Git Flow and I'm really appreciated the flexibility it provides.

The problem is, in the following situations, may I working on and commit to a development branch directly?

- a minor typo fix,
- or a small method-level refactor,
- or some errors fixes after a feature was merged.

I've read the [creator's post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and there is no mention of this situation. What you guys doing in real world?

Comment: Imo this question is primarily opinion-based which in turn means there is no *true* answer.

Comment: the answer is also in the link you've mentioned. Look carefully the graph. Just above the merge `1.3.0-unstable.1` there is a commit directly done on the develop branch.

Answer (score 10):

Totally.  The benefit of isolated feature branches in git flow is primarily for the people who requested them.  As long as it is a code change that you are *sure* is ok to go into the next release, it can be made directly into develop.  You don't want to bog down your team with too many feature branches if you can help it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is up to you. What we've done in our project is try and have everything on a branch and then when we are about to release, merge what we definitely want in the release back to develop. Then we create our release branch from develop. I say we have done everything on a branch but for typos and very minor fixes we dont tend to create a branch.